# Creating a relocatable shared library with binutils

Tags: shared-libraries, elf, ld, binutils

I have a custom toolchain that generates relocatable shared libraries. This works with an equally custom ELF loader which loads these into memory, fixing them up. I am now trying to persuade gcc and binutils to produce ELF files that are compatible with this loader.

Unfortunately, it would appear that binutils is refusing to generate *relocatable* shared objects. It'll generate PIC shared objects, but I don't want to do this due to the extra overhead of the GOT/PLT (and besides, the custom ELF loader doesn't support it). And it'll generate relocatable objects, but then they're not dynamic objects and so don't have the appropriate sections the ELF loader wants to be able to load them.

I'm not clear as to why GNU ld refuses to allow me to specify --relocatable and -shared on the same command line. Can anyone enlighten me? And does anyone know the incantation to make ld generate the object files I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I see nobody has answered this question, so I think I'll try.

I'll try to show how this works by means of a practical example.  Here is some C code, which has an artificial but purposeful mix of external global functions and data -- the bread and butter of relocations.

```
/* hello.c */
char* hello = "hello";

/* say.c */
#include "stdio.h"
extern char* hello;
void say(void){
    printf(hello);
}

/* main.c */
extern void say(void);
void please_say(void){
    say();
}
int main(void){
    please_say();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the usual way to get a shared object/library would be to compile each C file with -fPIC, and link the lot with -shared.  After we do that, we can use readelf to examine the relocations.  Something like this:

```
gcc -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -o libtemp.so *.o

readelf -r libtemp.so
```

The relocation data is as follows:

```
Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x34c contains 6 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
000016dc  00000008 R_386_RELATIVE
000016e0  00000008 R_386_RELATIVE
000016ac  00000106 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __gmon_start__
000016b0  00000206 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   _Jv_RegisterClasses
000016b4  00000d06 R_386_GLOB_DAT    000016e0   hello
000016b8  00000406 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __cxa_finalize

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x37c contains 5 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
000016c8  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __gmon_start__
000016cc  00000507 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   000004fc   please_say
000016d0  00000807 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000540   say
000016d4  00000307 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   printf
000016d8  00000407 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __cxa_finalize
```

The R_386_GLOB_DAT item for hello is a GOT entry.  Similarly, the R_386_JUMP_SLOT items for say, please_say and printf are PLT entries.  They come from the use of position independent code, not the fact that we have made a shared object.

After doing the same build process without -fPIC, we get different relocations. So

```
gcc -c *.c
gcc -shared -o libtemp.so *.o

readelf -r libtemp.so
```

gives us

```
Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x34c contains 9 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00001674  00000008 R_386_RELATIVE
00001678  00000008 R_386_RELATIVE
000004d3  00000802 R_386_PC32        000004f0   say
000004e0  00000502 R_386_PC32        000004cc   please_say
000004f7  00000d01 R_386_32          00001678   hello
000004ff  00000302 R_386_PC32        00000000   printf
00001654  00000106 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __gmon_start__
00001658  00000206 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000165c  00000406 R_386_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __cxa_finalize

Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x394 contains 2 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0000166c  00000107 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __gmon_start__
00001670  00000407 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   __cxa_finalize
```

Now the shared object has familiar relocations for all the definitions.  There is an absolute relocation of hello, and PC relative relocations for the functions.

What does this mean?  Well the are GOT and PLT tables are still there.  There are two important things to note.  The first is that there are no GOT or PLT entries for the compiled code.  The second is that the GOT and PLT tables are still needed.  They are being used for initialisation and cleanup (possibly for the standard library).  Since you are using a custom ELF loader, it would probably be advisable to implement some basic support for GOT and PLT entries, even if your main application does standard relocations instead.

Your application will then pay the price of relocation, but not of position independence.